# Inno Setup: How to registry multiple files in order to open in one instance?

Tags: inno-setup

I would like to register own extension filename to own developed software during installation process.

I wrote a script with Inno Setup in [Registry] section. However, it opens one instance for each file.

What I need is, if I select two or more files and right-click to open them, just only one instance will be open with these files in.

Like if I type in command line: `<executable file> <file1> <file2>`

How can I do it with Inno Setup ?

Comment: Basic file associations will launch an instance of the application for each file, this is something you need to deal with in your application code by looking for an existing instance on startup and using IPC of some kind to forward the command line for processing to the existing instance.

Comment: Do you mean, there is nothing to do with Inno Setup ?

Comment: Yes, the exe that's run in response to the file association needs to be able to deal with multiple files

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826791/how-to-pass-in-multiple-file-folder-paths-via-a-right-click-event-verb-to-an-e

Comment: Now deprecated, you could (can?) use DDE. Only one instance involved, no need to pass information from one instance to another. At inno side, all you need is a few more [entries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh127429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). At application side you need to  implement DDE server conversation.

Comment: .. or implement IDropTarget in the application to similar effect with probably a little more work.