# 8.3 format filenames received when files opened from context menu in Windows

Tags: windows, winapi

I have edited the windows registry so that selected files can be opened with the program I made (from an option in context menu). Specifically, under specific file types I have added 'shell' key and under it a 'command' key with string containing "C:\MyProgram.exe %1". The file opens correctly, however my program receives the file name in old 8.3 format, and I need full file name for display. How should I fix this?

Side quest: How to open multiple files as multiple arguments in one program call instead of opening separate instances, each with only one argument(%1)?

Comment: It is not normal.  Don't obfuscate the program name, show us its manifest and the dumpbin.exe /headers output.

Comment: Strangely it didn't happen again after next restart but I don't want to risk so I implemented IInspectable's answer.

Comment: I suspect we'll hear back from you some day so this could become a useful Q+A.  Like when the short path fits but the long path exceeds MAX_PATH, nasty failure mode.

Comment: @HansPassant Nop, just tested it, works very fine after I implemented IInspectable's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get to the full path name is to call [GetLongPathName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364980.aspx). In C++ you would use something like the following:

```
std::wstring LongPathFromShortPath(const wchar_t* lpszShortPath) {

    // Prevent truncation to MAX_PATH characters
    std::wstring shortPath = L"\\\\?\\";
    shortPath += lpszShortPath;

    // Calculate required buffer size
    std::vector<wchar_t> buffer;
    DWORD requiredSize = ::GetLongPathNameW(shortPath.c_str(), buffer.data(), 0x0);
    if (requiredSize == 0x0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("GetLongPathNameW() failed.");
    }

    // Retrieve long path name
    buffer.resize(static_cast<size_type>(requiredSize));
    DWORD size = ::GetLongPathNameW(shortPath.c_str(), buffer.data(), 
                                    static_cast<DWORD>(buffer.size()));
    if (size == 0x0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("GetLongPathNameW() failed.");
    }

    // Construct final path name (not including the zero terminator)
    return std::wstring(buffer.data(), buffer.size()-1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick, and I avoided using external libraries.

Comment: Btw line 15, VS 2010 requires 'size_type' to be declared as 'vector<wchar_t>::size_type'.

Answer (score 0):

For first part of question do that IInspectable suggested.

But if you want to do something more fancy, simple registry modification will not do the trick. You need [Windows Shell Extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Explorer#Extensibility) and implement [Context Menu handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776881.aspx). Once I have made one, here are some useful links: [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/ATLShellExtContextMenuHandl-e5c5fc23), [here](http://yanaware.com/com4me/ShellExtGuide1.php-author=Michael%20DUNN&mail=mdunn@inreach.com&url=http---home.inreach.com-mdunn&idTute=2.htm) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codefx/archive/2012/05/15/sample-of-may-15th-c-windows-shell-context-menu-handler.aspx). And there are already similar questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826791/how-to-pass-in-multiple-file-folder-paths-via-a-right-click-event-verb-to-an-e)

Comment: Thanks, I searched for an answer but didn't find some of those answers, they are exactly what my second question was about.