# How to Pass MULTIPLE filenames to a Context Menu Shell Command?

Tags: windows, shell, registry, contextmenu, windows-shell-extension-menu

Passing a single filename to a context menu shell command is simple:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\MyProgram\Command]
@="program.exe %1"
```

But if I select multiple files, `program.exe` is invoked for *each* such selected file.

What I would like to do instead is invoke`program.exe` only once, passing to it all the filenames currently selected.

How to do this?

Comment: I've successfully added an item to file context-menu (`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell`). The item shows up when I right-click on a file. When I select multiple files and then right-click, it doesn't show up. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821662/how-to-add-new-items-to-right-click-event-on-folders-and-files-in-windows/1824064#1824064), as it says that this isn't really possible to pass multiple files to a single instance and you must rely on some form of IPC(Inter process Communication).

Answer (score 34):

You can use [Send To](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/customize-the-windows-vista-send-to-menu/) for this. It supports multiple files.

In case this website goes offline:

Open `shell:sendto` with `Windows + R` or paste it into your explorer address bar. It should redirect you to:

`C:\Users\<yourusername>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo`

Create a shortcut to your program in this folder and you should see it in your explorer right-click menu under `Send to`

Comment: It seems there's a limit to how many files can be sent depending on the files' path. I can send 504 files with paths `C:\test\001.txt`. 504 file names amount to 7560 chars (no space), 8063 chars (space delimited). Sending 505 files (7575 chars [no space]; 8079 [space delimited]) doesn't work.

Comment: Saved me so much time. I use it for compare software.. Thanks

Comment: When trying to pass the file `G:\New [folder] (4)\Untitled-2.txt` to a Powershell script, the result becomes `G:\New [folder] 4 \Untitled-2.txt`. It seems that parentheses cannot be parsed correctly. Any solution?

Comment: @preachers try escaping parenths with a back tick: `G:\New [folder] \`(4\`)\Untitled-2.txt`

Answer (score 0):

#### Use: Command-Queuer.cmd

I wanted to do the same thing and ended up creating a 'wrapper' .cmd/bat file to queue the commands for me... I use a temporary queue file to: (a) self-nominate a control instance to run the process, and (b) signal to other instances not run the command(s) directly and instead just add their file/parameters to the queue and exit. The script waits X seconds for the other instances to queue their info and then processes the selected files sequentially.

```
Command-Queuer.cmd
------------------

@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

:: SETUP PARAMETERS: Control temp file location and delay before running
SET QueueFile="%TEMP%\Multi-Item-Queue.txt"
SET /A Secs=5

:: MAIN PROGRAM: If the first instance create the queue and wait, otherwise transfer to queue and exit
IF EXIST %QueueFile% ( ECHO %* >> %QueueFile% ) ELSE (
    ECHO %* > %QueueFile%
    ECHO Waiting %Secs% seconds for other files to finish queuing then will activate...
    TIMEOUT /T %Secs% /NOBREAK >nul
    
    REM - ADD YOUR CODE HERE TO PROCESS THE QUEUE FILE AS A WHOLE
    REM - Example: Display popup of all file paths selected: Msg %username% <%QueueFile%
    
    REM - ALTERNATIVELY, ITERATE THROUGH EACH LINE OF THE FILE
    REM - Example: FOR /F "tokens=*" %%Z in (%QueueFile%) DO ( COPY %%Z "C:\Backup" )
    
    :: Delete the queue file when finished
    DEL %QueueFile%
)
GOTO:EOF
```

NOTE: You will see a empty cmd window appear for a split-second for each file selected, i.e. if you select 30 files then 30 cmd windows will briefly appear, but these can be hidden if desired please check: [Run a batch file in a completely hidden way (superuser.com)](https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-batch-file-in-a-completely-hidden-way)

Answer (score 0):

I created a small program that completely solves this problem. https://github.com/ge9/ExecuteCommand-Pipe

It is based on this Microsoft sample code: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/appshellintegration/ExecuteCommandVerb

It uses COM (Component Object Model) technology of Windows, so there are no restriction on the number or path length of passed files. Also it doesn't involve any inter-process communication, preserving the order of files. The command for opening files is specified in registry values. See the repository for details.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the code here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.