# Context menu on explorer using wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I had created an application that doing some stuffs with image using wpf.

I want to integrate this application with windows explorer context menu.

So that when user select image files in explorer (suppo se desktop) and click on the created menu it open with my program.

I had achieved this by adding a registry value like
MyprogramName %1

Where %1 is pointing to the selected file path.
This works fine but 
When user selects multiple image then my program also open multiple times and process the image.

I want to create a menu and its submenu (with icon)  in such a way that multiple files will pass to my program all at once. Like winrar is doing such things

Kindly help.

Regards
Amit

Comment: Try to see this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440715/how-to-pass-multiple-filenames-to-a-context-menu-shell-command

Comment: Thanks for the reply Igor. I found the sharpshell library and follow the steps to create context menu but when i trying to register the dll it shows 'dll is not a sharpshell server' through server manager tools and I also tried registration through regasm it also shows it is not a valid .net assembly. Kindly help