# How does "send to" manages input arguments? (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, registry, contextmenu, argument-passing

Background: I want to add my application to the windows context menu, I have done this by adding a new key to the windows registry:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\myapp
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\myapp\command
```

And assigning the default value of the "command" key to the location of my exe, plus an extra argument:

```
value = "c:\users\john\myapp\myappexe.exe" "%1" arg1
```

It works, i can 'right click' any file and run my application with that file. The problem comes when I try to select multiple files, it opens as many windows of my app as files selected, I want to be able to handle all the inputs with one instance of my program.

I'm aware that this may be solved by creating shell extensions as posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/425940/how-can-i-create-a-shell-context-menu-item-that-takes-multiple-files-as-argument), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20740846/windows-explorer-right-click-context-menu-for-files-and-folders), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826791/how-to-pass-in-multiple-file-folder-paths-via-a-rigth-click-eventverb-to-an-ex) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821662/how-to-add-new-items-to-right-click-event-on-folders-and-files-in-windows/1824064#1824064). Creating a full functional shell extension is out of the scope of my (small) project, and I haven't found tutorials which I can understand.

Problem: I'm looking a way around it, and I found that a program called from the "send to" folder in windows is able to handle multiple files, for example, if i put the execulable of this code (c++) in the `C:\Users\john\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo` folder,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    for(int i=0;i<=argc;i++){
        cout << argv[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

...select a bunch of flies, and drag them into the executable, I'll get in **one window** the path of all the selected files (send to [tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/customize-the-windows-vista-send-to-menu/)). How does this work? Can I use this behavior and apply it to my app?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to design your application so that any newly launched instance checks for a pre-existing instance (you could use a mutex to do this) and then forwards the command-line parameters to that one, encapsulated in a message of some kind. The original instance can then take the appropriate action.